# why login doesn't automatically go to dashboard using firebase and flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm creating login authentication, login has been successful but to enter the dashboard it doesn't go directly to the redirect but has to restart the android emulator, below is the code I made

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/get_core.dart';
import 'package:get/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart';
import 'package:surveys/presentation/home/authServices.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}
    
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
        
    final emailC = TextEditingController();
    final passwordC = TextEditingController();
        
    void login(String email, String password) async {
      FirebaseAuth _auth =  FirebaseAuth.instance;
      User? user;
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password);
        user = userCredential.user;
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
          print('No user found for that email.');
        } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
          print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
        }
      }
    }
```

here I call login

```
onPressed: () {
  //login(context);
  login(emailC.text, passwordC.text);
                                      
},
```

Comment: It seems to me that you create a variable to hold the user, then log the user in, and then the function ends, immediately discarding said user, that is why you have an issue, but in order to help you solve it, would you mind posting the code for your build method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
Future<String> loginwithemailandpassword(String email,String password) async {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      UserCredential result = await firebaseauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
     if(result != null)
  {
    setState(() {
      user = result.user;
    });
    return "Success";
  }
  else
  {
    return "Unsuccess";
  }


      
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      //print(error.code);
      if (error.code == "invalid-email") {

        return "Invalid Email";
      } else if (error.code == "user-disabled") {

        return "User Disabled";
      } else if (error.code == "user-not-found") {

        return "User not found";
      } else if (error.code == "wrong-password") {

        return "Wrong Password";
      } else {

        return "Unknown Error";
      }
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      print("Socket Exception Error $e");

      return "Network Error";
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {

      print("Timeout Error $e");

      return "Timeout Error";
    } catch (e) {

      print("UnExpected Error::$e");
      return "UnExpected Error";
    }
  }
```

Then OnPressed Write Following Code:

```
onPressed: () async{
  //login(context);
  String message = await loginwithemailandpassword(emailC.text, passwordC.text);
  if(message == "Success")
  {
     //Do Navigate Like Following
     Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Dashboard()),);
  }
  else
  {
      print(message);
  }
                                      
},
```

Comment: While this may answer question, can you please add details explaining why this is working?

Comment: I always think that making a return function is better than void because you can use that return value to check whether its function is over or not. And you also make it user-friendly by putting a snack bar in else function to show the user what error he is facing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `Navigator` to `Dashboard Screen`

In your case:

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password);
    user = userCredential.user;
    if(user != null){
    setState(() {
      _success = true;
      user = user.email;
    });
    }
    else{_success = false;}

} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
}
```

Then trigger `_success`

```
    If(_success )
    {
        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Dashboard()),);
    }
```

Comment: still not redirect to dashboard